# Basic Property of Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ probability space. Let $B \subseteq F$. Let $X,Y \in  \mathcal{L}^1(P)$

I know, that:
$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]$

But, is this legal?
$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]= \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[0|B]\right]$

If not, how can I take the $X$ out of the second integral?

Comment: "I know, that: $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]$" Actually, no, $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]=\mathbb{E}[X|B]$, which is not equal to $\mathbb{E}[X]$ in general. You might be confusing conditional expectation with respect to a sigma-algebra and conditional expectation with respect to an event.

Comment: What is the difference. Or, where can I read more about this theory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation

Comment: If $U = \mathbb{E}[X|B]$, and $U \in \mathcal{L}^1$, and $U$ is $B$-measurable, and $\int_B UdP = \int_B X dP$, does it hold, that: $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]?$

Comment: ?? Again, $E(X\mid B)$ is a constant, not a random variable.

Comment: @Did $B \subseteq F$, not $B \in F$. $E[X|B]$ still constant?

Comment: There is no canonical definition of $E(X\mid B)$ when $B$ is not, either (i) an event with positive probability, or (ii) a sigma-algebra. @gariban Please explain.

Comment: @Did Edited further

Comment: What do you want me to explain, @Did ?

Comment: What you are referring to when you are writing: $E(X\mid B)$, for $B$ a strict subset of the sigma-algebra $F$.

Answer (score -1):

#### If $B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $B \subseteq F$

> $$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]= \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[0|B]\right]$$

is wrong because

$$RHS = \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[0|B]] = E[X(0)] = 0$$
$$LHS = \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X|B]] = E[X\right]$$

For any $E[X]\ne0$, we have our contradiction.

Now if $X\in mB$, then

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]= \mathbb{E}[X \mathbb{E}[1|B]\right]$$

As for 'taking $X$ out of the second integral', there might not exactly be a second integral there: $\mathbb{E}[X|B]$ is merely notation for any $B$-measurable and integrable random variable $Z$, in the same probability space as X, such that

$$\int_G Z dP = \int_G X dP \ \forall \ G \ \in \ B$$

Thus, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[X|B]\right] = \mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_{\Omega} Z dP$$

I see only one integral there.

---

#### If $B$ is an event, i.e. $B \in F$, and assuming $P(B) > 0$, then we have

$\mathbb{E}[X|B] := \frac{\mathbb{E}[X1_B]}{P(B)}$, which is a number.

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|B]]= \mathbb{E}[X|B]\mathbb{E}[1]= \mathbb{E}[X|B](1)= \mathbb{E}[X|B]$$